# Counting number of values between interval

Tags: python, arrays, count

Is there any efficient way in python to count the times an array of numbers is between certain intervals? the number of intervals i will be using may get quite large

like:

```
mylist = [4,4,1,18,2,15,6,14,2,16,2,17,12,3,12,4,15,5,17]

some function(mylist, startpoints):
   # startpoints = [0,10,20]
   count values in range [0,9]
   count values in range [10-19]

output = [9,10]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will have to iterate the list at least once.

The solution below works with any sequence/interval that implements comparision (`<`, `>`, etc) and uses [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect) algorithm to find the correct point in the interval, so it is very fast.

It will work with floats, text, or whatever. Just pass a sequence and a list of the intervals.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import bisect_left

def count_intervals(sequence, intervals):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    intervals.sort()
    for item in sequence:
        pos = bisect_left(intervals, item)
        if pos == len(intervals):
            count[None] += 1
        else:
            count[intervals[pos]] += 1
    return count

data = [4,4,1,18,2,15,6,14,2,16,2,17,12,3,12,4,15,5,17]
print count_intervals(data, [10, 20])
```

Will print

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {10: 10, 20: 9})
```

Meaning that you have 10 values <10 and 9 values <20.

Comment: cool! now how do i sort the values (and maintain the order of the interval endpoints)? i added a few values to mylist, and it came out as defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {40: 1, 10: 6, 30: 6}).

Comment: dicts don't have order. you can use something like: `for k in sorted(mydict): print k, mydict[k]`

Comment: or: `for value in intervals: print value, result[value]`

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was just wondering how can this be modified such that if there are no values in an interval the list will contain interval: 0. I.e. if we typed count_intervals(data,[10,20,30]) we get the result defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {10: 10, 20: 9, 30:0}).

Comment: @JamesElder `for value in intervals: result.setdefault(value, 0)`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how large your list will get but here's another approach.

```
import numpy as np
mylist = [4,4,1,18,2,15,6,14,2,16,2,17,12,3,12,4,15,5,17]
np.histogram(mylist, bins=[0,9,19])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a combination of value_counts() and pd.cut() to help you get the job done.

```
import pandas as pd   
mylist = [4,4,1,18,2,15,6,14,2,16,2,17,12,3,12,4,15,5,17]
split_mylist = pd.cut(mylist, [0, 9, 19]).value_counts(sort = False)
print(split_mylist)
```

This piece of code will return this:

(0, 10] 10
(10, 20] 9
dtype: int64

Then you can utilise the to_list() function to get what you want

```
split_mylist = split_mylist.tolist()
print(split_mylist)
```

Output: [10, 9]

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are integers, as in your example, representing the intervals as frozensets can perhaps be fastest (worth trying).  Not sure if the intervals are guaranteed to be mutually exclusive -- if not, then

```
intervals = [frozenzet(range(10)), frozenset(range(10, 20))]
counts = [0] * len(intervals)

for n in mylist:
  for i, inter in enumerate(intervals):
    if n in inter:
      counts[i] += 1
```

if the intervals are mutually exclusive, this code could be sped up a bit by `break`ing out of the inner loop right after the increment.  However for mutually exclusive intervals of integers >= 0, there's an even more attractive option: first, prepare an auxiliary index, e.g. given your `startpoints` data structure that could be

```
indices = [sum(i > x for x in startpoints) - 1 for i in range(max(startpoints))]
```

and then

```
counts = [0] * len(intervals)
for n in mylist:
  if 0 <= n < len(indices):
    counts[indices[n]] += 1
```

this can be adjusted if the intervals can be < 0 (everything needs to be offset by `-min(startpoints)` in that case.

If the "numbers" can be arbitrary floats (or `decimal.Decimal`s, etc), not just integer, the possibilities for optimization are more restricted.  Is that the case...?